# Change primary and foreign keys to integer in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have some tables with data like

- company (compid, name, address)
- country (countryid, name)

Each company operates in a country and there is a table

being(compid,countryid) with external keys

The compid and countryid are varchar like company001, country112

1)I want to change them to integer keys. How this can be done assuming we have data in the table?

2. The first maybe a bit easier. The challenge is with the foreign keys.  Especially in the table 'being' how to do the mapping will  from existing old varchar to the assigned integer keys automatically (or bulk change)?

Is there any way to modify existing data and convert e.g. the country key coutry112 to 112 with SQL command? Even in a new column?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that cascading foreign key constraints will change the *type* of a column.

So, drop all foreign key constraints, change the types, and recreate the foreign keys.

1. Drop all foreign key constraints.

   ```
    alter table <table name> drop constraint <constraint name>;
   ```
2. Change the type in the parent tables:

   ```
    alter table countries alter column countryid
        set data type int using ((regexp_match(countryid, '[0-9]+$'))[1]::int);

    alter table companies alter column companyid
        set data type int using ((regexp_match(companyid, '[0-9]+$'))[1]::int);
   ```
3. Change the type in the child tables using the same structure as above.
4. Recreate the foreign key constraints.

Comment: I might not put the question properly. I can add a new integer key in the main tables. The problem is how can I update the tables that they use the old foreign key with the new integer key (eg autoincrement). Is there any command than I can update the old foreign key with the new quickly? Like update and set the new foreign key

Comment: @Anti76 . . . You should ask a new question if you have different columns.  The title of this question seems to be clearly about changing the values in place.  I mean, you can use the `regexp_match()` expression to extract the number from the current value -- if that is the integer being used.